# What is the German loan word?

Tags: meaning, don-delillo, underworld

Is there a particular word here that's the "German loan word" or what's the intended meaning?

> When you think about the textured histories of the teams
> and the faith and passion of the fans and the way these forces are entwined
> citywide, and when you think about the game itself, live-or-die, the third game in a
> three-game playoff, and you say the names Giants and Dodgers, and you calculate
> the way the players hate each other openly, and you recall the kind of year this has
> turned out to be, the pennant race that has brought the city to a strangulated
> rapture, an end-shudder requiring a **German loan-word** to put across the mingling
> of pleasure and dread and suspense, and when you think about the blood loyalty,
> this is what they're saying in the booth—the love-of-team that runs across the
> boroughs and through the snuggled suburbs and out into the apple counties and the
> raw north, then how do you explain twenty thousand empty seats?

This is from Don DeLillo's *Underworld*.

Comment: A Google search brings up a book that suggest "Götterdämmerung" (apparently because this is about a kind of rapture). https://books.google.de/books?id=vKDFAh7vqQUC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=german+loanword+delillo&source=bl&ots=c-8woP-cKl&sig=ACfU3U1eyU9abgPQg33flYiik1T0CrQvTA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbq6O9us7wAhUBLewKHT-XDJYQ6AEwBHoECAkQAw#v=onepage&q=german%20loanword%20delillo&f=false

Comment: 'requiring **a** German loan-word' (not '**the** German loan-word').

Comment: @EikePierstorff yea tbh that's the only related German loan word I know of (from a biography on Hitler I read) so I just assumed it was "something like that".

Comment: @usretc:...yes? If someone said they had to pick a word, you would then ask "What's the word you picked?" Not "What's a word you picked?"

Comment: I would not assume that DeLillo had a *specific* word in mind. It's rather like [Lovecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft) obliquely describing "unspeakable colors" and "eldritch horrors from outer space" without actually, you know, *describing* those colors and horrors. That way, every reader is free to supply their own imagination of what such colors or horrors might be... just like you can here here fill in your own preconception of what German loan-words would be appropriate. The remaining uncertainty leaves an additional *frisson* - in both cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a concrete loan word that applies here. I think DeLillo alludes to the fact that there is a certain group of German loan words (*angst*, *unheimlich* etc) that are used when dealing with certain complex or even existential issues. It seems necessary that the complexity of a "mingling of pleasure, dread and suspense" would require such a loan word if one were to compress these feelings into a single word.

Comment: Two more German loanwords in a similar direction are *schadenfreude* (pretty well-known, like *angst*) and *weltschmerz* (more obscure, like *unheimlich*).   None of these precisely fits the quote’s context, but together, they build up the group of loanwords DeLillo is alluding to.

Comment: I think there is an additional element of how German is known for **long compound words** which can capture a set of ideas in a single word. So it's not just that German has words like *Angst* which refer to complex emotions, but also that German could conceivably fit pleasure, dread, suspense etc. into a single word.

Comment: "German loanword" implies that the word is *adopted* from German. The long compound words you are probably thinking are not very likely to get adopted into the English language.

Comment: @Tsundoku not the ridiculously long memey ones, but Schadenfreude, Kindergarten etc. are all examples and are somewhat widespread

Comment: By the way, for non-native German speakers: be aware that "Angst" (in German) is a totally normal, everyday word and simply means "fear". The meaning attributed to it in the English loanword "angst" (i.e., "existential angst") is not what a German speaker would think about at all. So if a German is telling you that he has angst, no need to assume the worst, he may simply be afraid of spiders. ;)

Comment: @dbmag9 Perhaps German (as a language and a national character) is also particularly good at combining opposites? E.g. schaurig-schön, [Angstlust](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstlust), Schadenfreude, Nervenkitzel (*Angstlust* being a candidate for the loan word).

Comment: @Hobbamok My favorite quip: The German cultural influence on America can be summed up in the three most common German loan words: Gesundheit, kindergarten and blitzkrieg.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica hamburger?

Comment: @David542 ham (meat) burger (not a German word) ??

Comment: @Hobbamok Hamburger as it is used in the kitchen might refer to an origin from Hamburg, Germany (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger)

Comment: @yunzen yep, my bad. Thanks for this extra bit of random knowledge :)

Comment: @Hobbamok Random knowledge is a thing in Germany

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not referring to a specific German loanword or even an existing loanword. It's rather the requirement of some German loanword that is not an existing loanword in the English language yet (or even in the German language).

The process of achieving this loanword would be then to first find/invent a German word that discribes the feeling of *pleasure and dread and suspense* and then make this a loanword to the English language.

This is out of the common conception that the German language is very deep and universal in having a word for even the weirdest combination of feelings, which the English language lacks.

The definition of [require](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/require) in the Merriam-Webster dictionary has the meaning of *to demand as necessary or essential* at 2a. If we then replace *require* with *need* in the original phrase *requiring a German loan-word* the meaning will be more clear. The English language would need a loanword from German that would describe this mixture of feelings.